# Bluetooth with Raspberry pi 3 in Java: my BufferedReader hangs when receiving lots of data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arm

I have written a simple program in Java on my Raspberry Pi 3. What it does is basically plays animations and sounds on a TV, and the input it receives to know what to play are sent by an android tablet using bluetooth.

On the tablet side, I have a few sliders (ex:volume) that send data through bluetooth whenever they are changed. The tablet acts as a server and the code looks like this:

```
final BluetoothSocket clientSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
bufIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
bufOut = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( os ) );
```

And whenever I want to send data, I do the following in another thread:

```
bufOut.write("<message>blabla</message>");
bufOut.flush();
```

However, if I move the sliders frenetically, the program stops at some point at `bufOut.flush();`. My thought on this is that the other end of the socket on the RPi is full and prevents the tablet from sending any more data.

So, on the RPi, I am using bluecove library and the code I have looks like this:

```
connection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(serviceInDevice);
is = connection.openInputStream();
os = connection.openOutputStream();
bufIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
bufOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
```

And for receiving data, I do the following on another thread:

```
while(true) {
    String readLine = bufIn.readLine();
    //Process data...
}
```

Here, after a slider frenzy, just when the tablet hangs on its `flush()` function, the program hangs on the `readLine()`.
I have tried to test the state of `bufIn` once it seems stuck, using another thread and doing `System.out.println(bufIn.ready())`, but the thread also hangs on this line.
I have also tried to test the state of the inputStream `is` asynchronously by calling `is.available()`, but the return value is always 0.

I have tried changing the `BufferedReaders` and `BufferedWriters` to manipulating directly the `OutputStream` and `InputStream`, but the problem remains.

Adding a sleep on the sending part to avoid the oversending is not an option, because I also have to send audio data to the RPi and basically a lot of stuff.

Is there a known problem about bluetooth on the RPi, or am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the reason why the Bluetooth of my RPi freezes. The answer might not be very helpful to others, but I was using VNC to see the output of my raspberry on my computer, and as soon as I stopped using VNC the problem disappeared. So if anyone is wondering, VNC and Bluetooth simultaneously on the RPi is not recommended :p